# 9 patch efficiency dilemma

Tags: android, android-layout

I've a design for application which contains buttons similar in style but different in width and height. Those buttons contain several states like active/passive.

Right now I'm thinking about implementation of the layout and those buttons. Firstly, I could use 9 patch tool to get rid off button width dependency. Secondly, I could play dumb and get image for every button and every state.

Disregarding more extensive sd-space usage of the second approach, what are other inefficiencies that this method creates?

I'm particularly concerned about ram usage - is it better to use 9patch in my situation and why ? Am I right in my suggestion that in case of the 9patch approach the amount of ram to be used is going to be much less because of the image data, which would reside in a single back-data container ?

Thanks.

Comment: if you have only one resource (9 patch), you load it only once. Plus, the 9P is a smaller image